# Hg: Merging new files from a branch not appearing in default

Tags: merge, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a branch, A, that I am trying to merge into default.  Inside the A branch are files that are not in default.  I then set default as my local and "merge to local" from A. The mere completes, but the files in A do not appear in default and I'm not sure why.  I've checked my ignore list on both branches and these files do not appear. How can I determine why those files in A are not joining default?

Comment: could you include the exact cmds (including switches) you used, in sequence?

Comment: Have you previously deleted the files in the target branch? –

Comment: @Ringding It's possible.  Is there a way to correct the issue if this was the underlying cause?

Comment: I guess you should be able to hg revert -r A the deleted files, either during the merge or afterwards.